# Need to install eclipse jee but have a previous version already installed

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, eclipse

I installed Eclipse from the "Ubuntu Software Center" and is up and running.
But it was the the J2EE version; I am trying to run tomcat from within Eclipse and need the jee version.
I have downloaded `eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz` and need to install it in the directory that the SE version was installed in.
I have tried to uninstall it but Ubuntu does not think that it is installed.

```
david@ubuntu-parker:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse 
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package eclipse is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any suggestions? I have untarred it but not sure where to place it.
And not sure if just dropping it somewhere is a good idea.

Comment: I was able to uninstall Eclipse using the "Ubuntu Software Center" remove.

Comment: Okay. solved the rest. Dragged it into my home directory and created a link. Then placed the link on the desktop.  Launched it all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I met similar situation, I have downloaded the desired version from Eclipse download site, then untar it to ex /opt/EclipseTomcat as administrator while chmod of eclipse file as execute   "chmod +x"  then try to write ./eclipse while the terminal on the path of eclipse

Here you can have multi versions of Eclipse
You may also need to create .desktop file for your eclipse to make eclipse appears in the launch unity.

You may google about each task by yourself